# How to store Selenium Locators for both products (Web and Mobile app) in one single class?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We have a web site that also have mobile site, (not app)
I'm using C# Selenium WebDriver and our automation framework has 2 classes that
Describes the pages in sites, now i want to use the same classes that planed from one to the other but the DOM and LOCATORS (cssSelector,Id...) are different.
So I am thinking to take locators out of my code to a data source,
But how can I link two data sources (for mobile and Web) to one class for instant?
if you have simple example it will be nice 
Thanks
Eyal

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

In your case you'll get 2 classes: one for the web and one for the mobile app.

When getting the locators instead of instantiating your class you can use the Factory to get the appropriate locators. It will check the platform and return the right object.